# I want to make a mpeg-2 decoder

Tags: video, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-2

Recently, I have got interested in mpeg-2 standard. And it suddenly occurred to me that i want to make a mpeg-2 decoder. I'm already studying mpeg system part that covers stream-packaging mechanism like transport stream or program stream. But I also want to know the structures of video and audio elementary stream. I actually mean to tell you that i really want to make my own mpeg-2 decoder.

Although there's a lot of great books regarding mpeg-2 system part, I couldn't find any of useful books that covers the structures of elementary streams and how you can process them properly. All i found was a book that explains how the video is encoded and all kind of encoding-technology stuff.

Would you guys suggest me a useful book to which i can actually refer when i'm processing a mpeg-2 file? hope you guys are willing to do it.

Comment: try to look into ffmpeg manual.

Comment: Isn't the ffmpeg a library for developers? you mean to tell me that i should look into ffmpeg source? or there's a documentation that covers all i mentioned?

Comment: isn't this site for developers? aren't you asking to develop something to decode MPEG2 ?

Comment: First of all, it is so nice of you to comment something so fast. I really appreciate that. What i'm saying is that i want to make a mpeg-2 decoder without any help of libraries like ffmpeg or something like that. Can you recommend a book or something that covers the structures of video and audio elementary streams and how i can process them properly to display pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout:
http://www.fh-friedberg.de/fachbereiche/e2/telekom-labor/zinke/mk/mpeg2beg/beginnzi.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-2

http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=22990

The 3rd link is the link to the MPEG-2 standard, this is the bible for MPEG-2 codec development. That will give you all the information needed to process a MPEG-2 file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would look into them.